# Null Commond line argument

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am passing around 9 parameter via command line to Node JS script.
Here is my Command:

```
node awsInvokeDelete.js DELETE https://Test1234.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com us-west-2 /qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/tdcloudtsttd03 AKIAJ4Y5DGqwewqeqw CFdAgsdtqweqwe/SKqDezdqweewofWrUXXBbQoMy   '{\"change_request\":\"chg0123456\"}'
```

I am passing query parameter as JSON in command line argument which is process.argv[9] in node JS script. It works perfectly If I pass value to all parameters but in some cases process.argv[8] will be empty. When I am passing empty value in process.argv[8], its actually takes argv[9] as argv[8].

how Can I pass empty argument value in command line for below script.

```
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
let awsMethod = process.argv[2],
    awsEndpoint = process.argv[3],
    awsRegion = process.argv[4],
    awsPathTemplate = process.argv[5],
    awsAccessKey = process.argv[6],
    awsSecreteKey = process.argv[7],
    awsPathParams = process.argv[8],
    awsAdditionalParams = JSON.parse(process.argv[9] || '{}');

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
   invokeUrl: awsEndpoint, // REQUIRED
   accessKey: awsAccessKey, // REQUIRED
   secretKey: awsSecreteKey, // REQUIRED
   region: awsRegion, // REQUIRED: The region where the API is deployed.
   retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if   
    request should be retried.  Uses axon-retry plugin.
    return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
  });


var param = awsPathParams;
// Template syntax follows url-template https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
var pathTemplate = awsPathTemplate;
var method = awsMethod;
var additionalParams = { queryParams: awsAdditionalParams, };
console.log(additionalParams);

var body = {};


apigClient.invokeApi(param, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
        //console.log(result.data + ": " +result)
        console.log(result.response.data)

    }).catch(function(result) {
        console.log(result.response.data)

    });
```

Here is output: args[8]'s value should be displayed as args[9]

```
args[8]: {"change_request":"chg0123456"}
args[9]: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script is not working on the input that you have provided (if you actually add the missing argument) because `'{\"change_request\":\"chg0123456\"}'` is not something that JS can parse as a JSON string. Furthermore, you are not passing any empty value in your input to the script (just an empty space is not considered as an actual input).

You need to change it to this `'{"change_request":"chg0123456"}'` and pass empty value as an empty string `''`.

This input works correctly.

```
node index.js DELETE https://Test1234.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com us-west-2 /qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites/tdcloudtsttd03 AKIAJ4Y5DGqwewqeqw CFdAgsdtqweqwe/SKqDezdqweewofWrUXXBbQoMy '' '{"change_request":"chg0123456"}'
```

If you really need the object in that format, then you need to remove `\` characters from it before you can call `JSON.parse` on it.

```
awsAdditionalParams = JSON.parse(
    process.argv[9].split('\\').join('') || '{}'
);
```

If you first want to check whether the last argument is not empty and only then run the code above, the you can use ternary operator like this.

```
awsAdditionalParams = process.argv[9]
    ? JSON.parse(process.argv[9].split('\\').join('') || '{}')
    : '';
```

Comment: Thanks Matus this is helpful. I have one more question, about adding If condition in node js script. I have modified my code to remove "\\" and then parsing the Json format and also passing '""' as empty string and works fine.

Comment: I have another question, if args[9] does not have any parameter means empty then how can I check if args[9] is empty, if not then only do  'JSON.parse(process.argv[9].split('\\').join('') || '{}');'

Comment: @KiranPatil I have added it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. change the script to switch around arguments 8 and 9. then you always have the same number even if 9 is empty.
2. pass the argument as "" instead of nothing.
3. change the script so you parse your own command line and change things around whichever way you like.